# Configuring Laravel and MongoDB extension for PHP (MAMP)

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, composer-php, mamp

I'm trying to use MongoDB with Laravel and the jenssegers/mongodb composer package for Laravel.

In order to do that, I need to get install the MongoDB extension for PHP (I'm using MAMP). I have spent 4 hours trying to figure it out, but it doesn't work.

I have tried do add extension=mongodb.so in my php.ini file. But I keep getting this error when I'm running composer update:

```
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

Any ideas what I can try next? I've been Googling a lot.

Comment: If you are on macOS, just use Valet instead and use homebrew for the rest.

Comment: Can you show the output of `php -m`

Comment: php -m doesn't show mongodb

I also get this error after adding extension=mongodb.so in to the php.ini file:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so'